# Why is it not possible to access GitHub when initializing a remote bash script via SSH locally?

Tags: bash, git, ssh

When connecting via SSH to the server, it's possible to pull from GitHub, but not when running 
 `ssh $SERVER bash $REMOTE_SCRIPT_PATH` locally.

The local keys are added both on the server and GitHub, but the local computer have different keys to GitHub than the server. Nevertheless both are granted access.

What is the difference from manually typing in the git commands after `ssh user@ip`, and telling SSH to run a bash script on the remote server? Or what am I missing here?

**local_script.sh**

```
SERVER=user@ip
REMOTE_SCRIPT_PATH=/home/user/remote_script.sh

function run()
{
  echo "Running: $@"
  "$@"
}

echo "---- Running deployment script on remote server ----"
run ssh $SERVER bash $REMOTE_SCRIPT_PATH
```

**remote_script.sh**

```
APP_DIR=/home/user/gitfolder

echo "---- Remote script ----"    
cd $APP_DIR/
git pull
```

**Terminal**

```
$ ./local_script.sh

---- Running deployment script on remote server ----
Running: ssh user@ip bash /home/user/remote_script.sh
---- Remote script ----
+ cd /home/user/
+ git pull git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

If I connect to the server via SSH and just type "git pull" everything is fine.

Comment: If you want a remote system to be able to use local keys, this is what *agent forwarding* is for. It may well be that you have that turned on in interactive use cases.

Comment: Running `ssh-add -l` locally, from your script, and then after manually connecting -- and comparing the results -- may be informative. Similarly, comparing the output of `declare -p SSH_AUTH_SOCK` between local and remote shells (unless it's *never* set, in which case the question becomes how remote ssh was ever able to authenticate -- unless you have a private key on the remote machine, but that's really not good form; ideally, your private keys don't live on any computer at all, but on a smartcard or yubikey you keep on your person).

Comment: ...store your keys on a computer, and anyone who gets into that computer can copy them and use the copies an unlimited number of times; store them on a physical hardware device and configure it to require a button press to use, and the worst an interloper can do is have that button press cause your computer to sign a request other than the one you intended.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy With `ssh-add-l` local from the script it uses different keys. With the other command the local says `../keyring/ssh` and on the server `../agent.67785`. I just don't get why the remote script can't access GitHub when it's not the local computer but the server itself who has the correct keys and is connecting to GitHub, and with the local computer having access to the server? Local has its own keys to GitHub, I guess I could try to forward those, but I just wonder why it works this way

Comment: If you want to see "why", that's what the verbose arguments to ssh are for -- compare `ssh -vv git@github.com`, and the logs will tell you which keys it's presenting to the remote server. Compare the set of keys presented in each case to the set of keys installed on your GitHub account, and there you are.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I see, but anyways I just don't get why there should be a hassle at all, since I log in via SSH as the user, on the server. I can use that user to pull from github, but i can't make that user run a script with git commands with the same credentials that gave me the permissions to begin with. It's not first and foremost a "problem solving" issue for me.

Comment: *nod*. Honestly, I don't know why either, but that's because I can't inspect your environment. If I were able to look over your shoulder and poke at it for a minute, I'm sure I'd find something anomalous -- dotfiles (that aren't used in noninteractive shells) modifying a pertinent environment variable, or PAM configuration doing likewise, or the like. There are lots of places where behavior is subtly different depending on whether stdin/stdout points to a TTY.

Comment: ...btw, since you *have* a `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` set on the server, but you say you have a a local key there that's what you want to use... does `unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK` change behavior? (Should make it fall back to `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, that being the default, unless you have something contrary specified in `~/.ssh/config` or similar).